# Marketing API restfb 1.33 JAVA

Tags: java, restfb

I  am  trying to integrate custom CRM to FaceBook.I am exploring restfb 1.33 API.We have reached till point where we are able to create CustomAudience  and add some new users to it.Idea is to have total CRUD control over created audiences.

I am looking for some code samples here.
String newpayload = createPayLoad().toString();
        System.out.println(newpayload);

```
    CustomAudience customaudience = client.publish("/" + audienceID + "/users",
            CustomAudience.class, Parameter.with("payload", newpayload));

    return customaudience;
```

custom retuns me null here may be because code returns immeditely and by that time facebook has not validated anything and it just retuns null object.

My Question is has any one used RestFB(No Spring social etc).to integrate or perform crud operations in a bulk mode

Comment: Already tried the Batch API? http://restfb.com/documentation/#batch-api-request

Comment: Yes we have tried the batchAPI.it turns out that,FB takes somewhat longer to match the audience with its internal matching mechanism.We saw the FB marketing audience column getting green after some like an hour .U can get approximate account of audience matched by quering the audience objects